# Make bootstrap-vue b-table sortable with bootstrap-vue-3 and vue 3

Tags: sorting, bootstrap-vue

I'm struggling to make my b-table sortable

I use :
"vue": "^3.2.13"

"bootstrap-vue-3": "^0.1.6"

Not sure what i'm doing wrong

Also, does it support filter and pagination ?

This is my vue for now

```
<template>
  <div class="overview">
    <b-table
        sort-by="status" sortDesc
        :items="items"
        :fields="formFields.licences"
    >
    </b-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "licences.vue",
  data(){
    return {
      formFields: {
        licences: [
          {key: "name", sortable: true,  label: "Name"},
          {key: "status", sortable: true, label: "Status"},
        ],
      },
      items: [
        { name: "Jack", status: "Used" },
        {name: "Frank", status: "Unused"},
        {name: "Larry", status: "Used" }
      ]
      }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code for sorting:

```
add it in b-table ->  v-model:sort-by.sync="sortBy"
      v-model:sort-desc.sync="sortDesc" 

return{
sortDesc:false
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).